# Android - Read news from website

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I'm making a Android application, where I need to read the latest news from this page (and the tab that says "NYHEDER":
http://www.stormthebuildingfest.com/
And afterwards, of course, print them out on the screen.

I've seen different places that maybe JSOUP could help with this problem - but the JSOUP cookbook doesn't seem to help me.

Is it even possible to fetch the news from this page? How?
Or if it is JSOUP - could anyone refer me to which part of the cookbook fits this problem? 
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you get an RSS or XML feed for the news? That'll make things much easier.

Comment: I'm kinda new to this, but is it possible with the website I want news from? Cause I'm willing to try if it is. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you need to do is this:

```
//This line will get you the whole page
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.url.com/section.script").get();

//This other line will make sure you get the specific info you're looking for
Elements elems = doc.select("some element");


//Or if you wanna just print it all out, you can simply
System.out.println(doc);

//You can also print just the text (Without ANY tags, or charset issues)
System.out.println(doc.text())

//The .text(); method works for you the variable Elements as
//well. If you got some info, and just want its text, that's
//the best way to go
```

In addition, I'd study the [Jsoup selector](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) API.

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried this. But when I debug the line
`Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("www.stormthebuildingfest.com");` I get "Source not found" error. And it doesn't continue to the next line?

Comment: Well, did you omit "http://", and .get();? The line below worked just fine for me: (NOTE: There's a blank space there just for it not to be recognized as a link)

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http:// www.stormthebuildingfest.com").get();

Comment: Somehow copying your code worked. Thanks a lot!
Working code below:
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc;     doc=Jsoup.connect("http:// www.stormthebuildingfest.com").get();

Comment: Now I see the problem! You might have been using the wrong import! Take a look at the class first lines. You might be using a Document class from some other package! (If you're using Eclipse, just ctrl + shift + o)

Comment: And if you wanna thank me, just +1 and/or accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function XML pull parser - for this to work there has to be a XML/RSS.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/watch-out-for-xmlpullparsernexttext.html

Good article on the theory.

Comment: Sorry if I seem stupid. But can I pull it as XML even if the link isn't XML?
Gonna check out the link!

Comment: No, you have to parse the XML within the tags. http://gta5news.com/feed I have the `title` tag and within that the data and comments. You need to parse this XML and sort to the information you need and populate a listview.

Comment: Hmm. But your link gta5news.com/feed gives me an actual XML-file, and that's is much easier to work with obviously. Any way I can make my link stormthebuildingfest.com into a XML? If not, how do I know the "hidden" tags? Cause if it's a XML-file like your link, I do know how to parse it.

Comment: That's the only way you can do it.